# Random Image Sequence Start Frame

Tags: image

I'm making a movie that has a scene that kind of imitates the speech scene in Star Wars 7. https://youtu.be/MPhHl2DpD4E?t=1m1s

Note how the storm troopers all perform similar motions but they are all slightly different? I realize that these storm troopers were probably 3D models, but in my scene, they will be a person in front of a green screen (thus alphamasked image sequences in a large array of planes). As I can't see a way for the random output from the object info node to plug into the image sequence offset, how can I randomly drive this parameter per each plane?

Comment: Can't help but think that it would be easier to create multiple unique versions of the plane with texture material, then use a script to add a driver to each that sources a random value? Perhaps you could multiply the random value by obj loc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a round about way to do it, and will not perfectly randomize the textures, but I used this technique to randomize a drawn animation of grass for a project last year.[image]

Comment: Hey, I guess that works :) I'll try it out and get back.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thanks for the answer. This seems like something that Python would clean up a lot, ya know? But it works!