# Randomizing the starting frame of an image sequence on a per object basis

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, animation-nodes

[image: Plugging the object info's "Random" value into the offset of an image sequence]

I'm trying to have the frame offset of an image sequence be randomized on a per-object basis.

Essentially, make it so that for every instance of the material, it starts from a different frame.

I know it's possible to make duplicate materials and change the offsets to random values by dragging the mouse, but I'm having hundreds of these and doing that for all of them would be a massive pain.

Comment: For anyone who's interested in this.see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/random-image-sequence-start-frame/114673)

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I have in mind is to use drivers.

Try plugging the random output to a Math node where you add 0 to it (just to have the value in some place you can address with a driver) and set a driver to the offset value, pointing the driver to the value in the Math node where you plugged the random.

I didn't try it yet, so I'm not 100% sure it will work.
If it doesn't let me know. Another alternative is to use Python.

Comment: I actually thought this was a great idea. I followed the steps, applying the driver to the frame offset and using the path ID I copied from where I plugged the random into the math node (I had to copy the ID before plugging in the value, because it wouldn't let me copy it after I plugged it in), but unfortunately, it seems that the way Blender works is that it only uses the value from a given parameter before it has been plugged into.